# Change Props on React Functional Component with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, react-functional-component

Title pretty much says it, I have looked for a few hours on how to change the props on a functional component using Enzyme. I have tried `wrapper.setProps({ foo: 'bar' })` but that obviously does not work for functional component. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i never used Enzyme, does this help ? https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2324

Comment: That does not help, but thanks for trying. @AlainIb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.setProps()` should work fine with RFC. see [doc](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.html#setpropsnextprops-callback--self)

E.g.

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Foo({ name }) {
  return <div className={name} />;
}

export default Foo;
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```js
import Foo from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('61688757', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo name="foo" />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.foo')).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('.bar')).toHaveLength(0);
    wrapper.setProps({ name: 'bar' });
    expect(wrapper.find('.foo')).toHaveLength(0);
    expect(wrapper.find('.bar')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61688757/index.test.jsx (11.714s)
  61688757
    ✓ should pass (12ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.992s
```

package versions:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
"jest": "^25.5.4",
"jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
```